# Minor GC pause times are increasing. What are the possible reasons?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We are experiencing increases in the minor GC pause times. 
The application is a server written in Java, executing 500 transactions per seconds. 
After a CMS collection the pause times **decreases** but after hours of running pause times increases again.
I've checked swap usage with *vmstat*, there isn't any swap input/output.

What are the possible reasons for increase in minor gc pause times?

Here is a part of the gc log file while the minor gc pause times are short: (0.01 seconds)

```
{Heap before GC invocations=123 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 306688K, used 275101K [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
  eden space 272640K, 100% used [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe90a50000)
  from space 34048K,   7% used [0xfffffffe92b90000, 0xfffffffe92df7718, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
  to   space 34048K,   0% used [0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe92b90000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3243264K, used 71097K [0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff5ac10000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 262144K, used 30336K [0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000)
2012-07-29T20:00:19.790+0300: 472.781: [GC 472.782: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 17432576 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 4)
- age   1:    1068432 bytes,    1068432 total
- age   2:     296272 bytes,    1364704 total
- age   3:      68624 bytes,    1433328 total
- age   4:      53776 bytes,    1487104 total
: 275101K->2187K(306688K), 0.0111305 secs] 346199K->73301K(3549952K), 0.0127033 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]
Heap after GC invocations=124 (full 0):
 par new generation   total 306688K, used 2187K [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
  eden space 272640K,   0% used [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe90a50000)
  from space 34048K,   6% used [0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe90c72dc0, 0xfffffffe92b90000)
  to   space 34048K,   0% used [0xfffffffe92b90000, 0xfffffffe92b90000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3243264K, used 71114K [0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff5ac10000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 262144K, used 30336K [0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000)
}
```

Below is a part of the gc log file while the minor gc pause times are long : (0.9 seconds)

```
{Heap before GC invocations=38526 (full 3):
 par new generation   total 306688K, used 280310K [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
  eden space 272640K, 100% used [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe90a50000)
  from space 34048K,  22% used [0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe911cda60, 0xfffffffe92b90000)
  to   space 34048K,   0% used [0xfffffffe92b90000, 0xfffffffe92b90000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3243264K, used 1023755K [0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff5ac10000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 262144K, used 34997K [0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000)
2012-07-31T13:21:46.709+0300: 149360.928: [GC 149360.930: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 17432576 bytes, new threshold 4 (max 4)
- age   1:    1794816 bytes,    1794816 total
- age   2:    2864408 bytes,    4659224 total
- age   3:      72672 bytes,    4731896 total
- age   4:      86160 bytes,    4818056 total
: 280310K->7605K(306688K), 0.9073290 secs] 1304066K->1031418K(3549952K), 0.9100161 secs] [Times: user=9.34 sys=0.15, real=0.91 secs]
Heap after GC invocations=38527 (full 3):
 par new generation   total 306688K, used 7605K [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
  eden space 272640K,   0% used [0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe80010000, 0xfffffffe90a50000)
  from space 34048K,  22% used [0xfffffffe92b90000, 0xfffffffe932fd490, 0xfffffffe94cd0000)
  to   space 34048K,   0% used [0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe90a50000, 0xfffffffe92b90000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 3243264K, used 1023813K [0xfffffffe94cd0000, 0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff5ac10000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 262144K, used 34997K [0xffffffff5ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000, 0xffffffff6ac10000)
}
```

**JVM args:**

```
-d64  -server  \
-XX:+UseParNewGC \
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-Xloggc:./logs/gc_"$DATE".log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \
-XX:+PrintGC \
-XX:PrintCMSStatistics=2 \
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution \
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC \
-XX:+PrintGCTaskTimeStamps \
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m \
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow \
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=16 \
-XX:ParallelCMSThreads=12 \
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE \
-Xms3500m -Xmx3500m -Xss192k
```

Comment: Regarding checking swap with vmstat - paging should never be an issue with a JVM, or we'd be talking about delays of a different magnitude altogether.  The gc times above differ only by a rough factor of 10.

Comment: What JVM version are you using?
Older version of JVM have bug with -XX:ParallelCMSThreads > 1. This bug prevents references (weak, soft, etc) to be correctly processed without full GC.
Your logs indeed seems strange. I would recommend add -XX:+PrintReferenceGC to verify reference processing time. If you application actively using weak or soft references it could be a cause.

Comment: @ilkinulas 6u25 is prety old I would recommend you to remove -XX:ParallelCMSThreads and add -XX:-CMSConcurrentMTEnabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a large eden space is surprisingly cheap, what is expensive is copying the objects which are retained.

In your shorter times you retained (the second size)

```
346199K->73301K, 0.0127033 secs
```

In your longer times you retained much more

```
1304066K->1031418K(3549952K), 0.9100161 secs
```

i.e. in the first case the GC took longer because you kept much more data.

The first thing I try in these cases is to increase the eden size, hoping that more objects will die before a collection occurs.

Comment: Can you explain why CMS or a full(system) gc decreases minor gc pause times?

Comment: A full GC shifts objects into the old gen. This means the young generation will be smaller (possibly almost empty) and it will take less time to clean up. As more objects are added to the young generation it will take longer to clean up again.

Comment: CMS have tenuring threshold set to 4 by default, there are exactly 4 generation of objects in both fragments of GC logs.

Comment: In first fragment GC were copying 2MiB in 12ms while in other it is show pause of 900ms while coping just 7MiB. Time to copy objects is definitively not a reason for such long pause.

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin The sizes I was looking at were basically the size of `concurrent mark-sweep generation total` used. It has to scan those to determine which object to keep. I haven't seen this being significant before, but this must take some time...

Comment: @PeterLawrey young collection does not need to scan old (concurrent mark-sweep generation). Total size (not used) of old space, indeed, indirectly affect young GC pause, but it is same in both cases.

Comment: @PeterLawrey any idea why minor gc time would relate to size of old gen size occupied, as it looks like the case above? From what i know, minor gc is probably related to the total size of old gen.

Comment: @AmmSokun to clean up the new gen (minor gc) it has to traverse the old gen to find objects retained. The more links from old gen to new gen, the longer it takes.

Answer (score 0):

new space only 300M while old space has 3500M?
you shoud enlarge new space's size.
provide your jvm arg if possible?